# Response.Redirect(url) throws error since the URL uses a proxy ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, proxy, response.redirect

I am trying to Redirect to a URL which uses certain proxy. I also made few changes in web.config and still it is not working.

Below changes were made in web.config

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="http://example.com:8080"
    bypassonlocal="False"
/>
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Then I try to redirect to a URL onClick of certain link using the below code

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

It throws error, but the same works when i try to get response using HttpRequest and HttpResponse as below. And when i debug, i could see the HttpRequest considering the Proxy that is configured in web.config.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        { 
            streamWriter.Close();
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string SessionID = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to redirect to this URL?

Comment: Can you provide more details? The code that works and the error message?

Comment: This questions needs some work. What is the URL that you are trying to redirect to? `Response.Redirect()` just takes the string you pass in and returns an http 302 response from the server with the new location. The only reason it would throw an error is null exception, using it on a callback, invalid string, or response already initiated. The proxy setting in IIS should only affect the outbound web requests from this application, nothing for the client. `Response.Redirect()` would not be altered by the proxy settings.